# Remove multiple of the same event handler using .off()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I assign two event handlers:

```
$('#myElement').on('click', '.classA', doSomething);
$('#myElement').on('click', '.classB', doSomethingElse);
```

I want to remove both the handlers. I know I can do:

```
$('#myElement')
    .off('click', '.classA')
    .off('click', '.classB');
```

I thought it would be possible in one line, but both of these fail:

```
$('#myElement').off('click', '.classA, .classB');
$('#myElement').off('click', '.classA .classB');
```

Is there a way to do it in one command?

Comment: Learned something new, You have to pass exact/original selector which you passed using `.on()`, so you have to use `$('#myElement')
    .off('click', '.classA')
    .off('click', '.classB');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the source, you will see in the [`off`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/test/data/jquery-1.9.1.js#L3774) :-

```
return this.each( function() {
    jQuery.event.remove( this, types, fn, selector );
}
```

Which means the selector needs to be exactly how it was created.

Therefore you need to use:-

```js
$('#myElement').on('click', '.classA', function() { alert('A'); });
$('#myElement').on('click', '.classB', function() { alert('B'); });

$('#myElement').off('click', '.classA').off('click', '.classB');

$('#myElement').on('click', '.classA', function() { alert('A'); });
$('#myElement').on('click', '.classB', function() { alert('B'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myElement">
  <button class="classA">A</button>
  <button class="classB">B</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically what I'm doing is as good as it gets by the look of it, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here you're using the dot-style namespaces to identify single handlers, it's fine, but as it's called "namespace" by jQuery docs, and its being look like css classes, it's more designed to match a group of handlers. So if you're not distinguishing the two events "classA" and "classB", you can just use "classCommon" for both of them, and unbind them together later using "classCommon", an example of which I just found on the [off's document page](http://api.jquery.com/off/)(see the last example, at the bottom of the page).

And sure as suggested by others above, all these has to happen on the same element. Same selector, to be exact. So if your question's about multiple HTMLElements, you'll need to change `#myElement` to `.elementsIWantToHandleTogether`.